# Questions about $\delta$ Dirac function-Fourier transform

Tags: fourier-analysis, dirac-delta

In my notes there is the following:
$$f(x)=\delta(x-x_0)$$
$$\text{The more closed a function is, the spectrum will be wider.}$$
$$\widetilde{f}(k)=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}{\delta(x-x_0)e^{-ikx}}dx$$
$$\widetilde{f}(k)=e^{-ikx_0}(*)$$ $$ |\widetilde{f}(k)|=1$$
$$$$
$$f(x)=\cos{(k_0x)}$$
$$\widetilde{f}(k)=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}{\frac{e^{ik_0x}+e^{-ik_0x}}{2}e^{-ikx}}dx=\frac{1}{2}[\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}{(e^{i(k_0-k)x}+e^{-i(k_0+k)x})}dx]$$
$$\widetilde{f}(k)=\frac{1}{2}[\delta(k+k_0)+\delta(k-k_0)](**)$$
$$$$
From the relation $$\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}{f(x) \delta(x-a)}dx=f(a)$$ we conlculde to the relation $(*)$.

Could you explain me how we conclude to the fact that $ |\widetilde{f}(k)|=1$ ??

I have also a question about the relation $(**)$:

We know that: $$2 \pi \delta(x)=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}{e^{ikx}}dk$$
So shouldn't it be:
$$\frac{1}{2}[\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}{(e^{i(k_0-k)x}+e^{-i(k_0+k)x})}dx]=\frac{1}{2}[ 2 \pi \delta(k_0-k)+2 \pi \delta(-k-k_0)]= \pi [  \delta(k_0-k)+  \delta(-k-k_0)]$$
Or do we conclude to that by an other way??

Last but not least, could you explain me the meaning of the following sentence?
$$\text{The more closed a function is, the spectrum will be wider.}$$

Answer (score 1):

1. The absolute value (modulus) of any complex exponential is $1$. The reason is that $|z| = \sqrt{z\bar{z}}$. If $z = e^{ikx_0}$, then $\bar{z} = e^{-ikx_0}$ and so $z\bar{z} = e^{-ikx_0}e^{ikx_0} = e^{-ikx_0+ikx_0} = e^0 = 1$.
2. These are actually the same. $\delta(x-x_0) = \delta(x_0-x)$ and $\delta(-x-x_0) = \delta(x+x_0)$. You can check these by integrating against functions. The factor of $2\pi$ occurs because you're not being consistent with where you put your $\frac{1}{2\pi}$. Fix this and it will work out the way you want. I'm *highly* against using a non-unitary version of the Fourier transform for this reason.

Your last sentence really needs some work but it is simply a realization of the Heisenberg uncertainty principle. If you have a narrow function, its Fourier transform is much wider and vice versa.

Comment: 1. I got it!!! 
$$$$
2. A ok!!! I use the following version of Fourier transform:
$$\text{Fourier transform } : \widetilde{f}(k)=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}{f(x)e^{-ikx}}dx$$
$$\text{Inverse Fourier transform } :f(x)=\frac{1}{2 \pi} \int_{- \infty}^{+ \infty}{\widetilde{f}(k) e^{ikx}}dk$$ Where should I have put the term $\frac{1}{2 \pi}$??

Comment: You should have had that $\tilde{f}(k) = 2\pi\left(\frac{1}{2}(\delta(k+k_0)+\delta(-k-k_0))\right)$ according to $2\pi\delta(k) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{ikx}dx$.

Comment: Yes, but at the relation $(**)$ there is no $\pi$..

Comment: My point is that there should be based on your observation that $2\pi\delta(k) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{ikx}dx.$

Comment: But I have found the same result as yours, or not? At the result that is in my notes there is no $\pi$.. Or have I understood it wrong?